# will asp run in .net 1.1 framework?

Tags: asp-classic, .net-1.1

I have an old asp app I am moving to a new server with .net 1.1 Will it run in this environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having any .Net version installed and enabled will not affect if classic asp runs.

You will however need to ensure that classic asp is enabled. (It is turned off on a default installation of IIS on Windows Server 2003).

Under IIS Manager select Web Service Extensions. Here you will see Active Server Pages along with the other installed extensions. It is here that you can allow or prohibit classic asp from running.

Answer (score 5):

Classic ASP pages can most definitely run side by side with .NET applications. You just have to make sure that Classic ASP pages are enabled in IIS (the later versions of IIS have Classic ASP extensions disabled by default, so you have to manually enable them).

**To check** (if Classic ASP is allowed):

IIS 7 - Select your server then open 'ISAPI and CGI Restrictions'. Make sure 'Active Server Pages' is 'Allowed'

IIS 6 - Select your server, expand the tree, and select 'Web Service Extensions'. Make sure 'Active Server Pages' is 'Allowed'

Answer (score 2):

YES!
Classic ASP runs on IIS, It has nothing to do with the fact that ASP.NET is installed too.

Answer (score 1):

yes absolutely, it very much will

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should run fine. However, as always you should test thoroughly. Migrating the site forward to ASP.NET is something that should be research thoroughly if you go that route as the paradigm is very different.